# How do I make the <div> in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want the div #container to be in the center of the page. Like horizontally and vertically. I tried to make `position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 50%; left: 50%; right: 50%` but it didn't work. And it has to be like in the center of the page no matter the size of the display. Thank you in advance!

Heres my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900|Droid+Sans:400,700|Josefin+Sans:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i|Oxygen:300,400,700|Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i');
 #container {
  width: 30em;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="main-head">
    <a href="#"><h2 id="main-heading">sKoolBook</h2></a>
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataCap = document.getElementById("chooseSchool").value;
        document.write(dataCap);
      </script>
      <form method="POST" id="chooseSchool">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: quick and dirty: {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)};

Comment: You're running your JS code too early on the page.

Comment: I don't have any JS code yet. And thank you @JonasGrumann. It worked!

Comment: @JonasGrumann transform: translate(-50%, -50%); would do the trick too (X & Y in one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">This div is centered</div>
```

Note: Transforms are pretty well supported by browsers nowadays, see http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Did you mean -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); and same for ms? I think -moz- should also be included if you decide to go with vendor prefixes (maybe even -o-). But honestly I think we can use them without vendor prefixes now, http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: I fixed it for you